# Trying to create a simple interface that allows us to get the temperature of a city using python(+ Tkinter) i keep getting KeyError: 'main'

Tags: python, api, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import requests

root=Tk() 

root.title("WEATHER API")
root.geometry("400x400")
city=StringVar()
def getweather():
      CITY=city.get()
      api_id="abb8cea2239face8fbb7401add34d73e"

      URL="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"+CITY+"appid="+api_id
      response=requests.get(URL)
      weatherinfo = response.json()
      if weatherinfo['cod']!='404':
         temp_kelvin=weatherinfo['main']['temp']
         temp_celsius=temp_kelvin-273
         temp_farhenheit=temp_celsius *(9/5) + 32
         Labelc=Label(temp_celsius)

         Labelf=Label(temp_farhenheit)
         Labelc.pack()
         Labelf.pack()
      else:
         error=Label(text="ERROR")
         error.pack()

city=Entry(root)
city.pack()
Mybutton=Button(root,text="CHECK STATS",command=getweather).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

To be very precise this is what I am getting `temp_kelvin=weatherinfo['main']['temp'] KeyError: 'main'`
Im a beginner in python, Isn't this related to dictionaries if yes then why is it wrong. The syntax seems fine.

Comment: Its clear that your error is saying that the data pulled from the json does not contain the value `main` as a key anywhere in the json file. Try printing the entire json first to see what keys exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to add to acw1668's corrections.

It is preferable to `import tkinter as tk` instead of doing `from tkinter import *`. This is going to help prevent overwriting of defined objects down the road as your code grows.

Next I would change some of your case sensitivity.
For example `URL` is all uppercase and in python like most languages this is to indicate a CONSTANT. Even though python does not have constants it is best practice to only use upper case like this if you intend for something to be treated like a constant in your code.

Next I would change all other labels to follow PEP8 standards. For example `Labelc` should look like `label_c`.

Next it appears that you first intended to use `city = tk.StringVar()` to hold your city value however you later define `city = Entry()`. It looks like you do not realize this is overwriting the first instance and the fact that `city.get()` is still working for you is due to the fact that both `Entry()` and `StringVar()` use `get()` to pull values form them so you may not have noticed this mistake. You can either use `Entry()` combined with `get()` or write it in a way that lets you use the string var in the entry field like this `tk.Entry(root, textvariable=city)`.

One last thing. In this case it is probably best to use a `try/except` statement to handle errors since you have the potential for a few things to fail. This will allow your code to have an error and print to console without causing any unwanted behavior if the url request fails.

Here is a an example of my changes combined with acw1668's into a workable code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('WEATHER API')
root.geometry('250x100')
city = tk.StringVar()
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=city).pack()


def get_weather():
    try:
        api_id = 'abb8cea2239face8fbb7401add34d73e'
        url = f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city.get()}&appid={api_id}'
        response = requests.get(url)
        weather_info = response.json()

        if weather_info['cod'] == 200:
            temp_kelvin = weather_info['main']['temp']
            temp_celsius = temp_kelvin-273
            temp_fahrenheit = temp_celsius * (9/5) + 32
            tk.Label(text=temp_celsius).pack()
            tk.Label(text=temp_fahrenheit).pack()
    except BaseException as e:
        tk.Label(text=f'ERROR: {e}').pack()


tk.Button(root, text='CHECK STATS', command=get_weather).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

One other note for those that need to use a proxy if your network has some restrictions on it.

For me to make this code work my URL had to grab from `http` instead of `https` and I had to use an internal proxy address that you can add into your `request.get()` like this:

```
url = f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city.get()}&appid={api_id}'
response = requests.get(url, proxies={'http': 'http://proxy.your_proxy_url_here.com:80'})
```

Comment: i have a huge scope for improvement ..Thanks!

Comment: @user17872805 Glad we could help. Make sure you select the answer that best solved your problem to indicate your issue is resolved. In this case I would say acw1668's answer was the 1st to post what was needed. I just added some extra.

Answer (score 3):

The URL is incorrect, it should be:

```
URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+CITY+"&appid="+api_id
```

It is better to use *f-string*:

```
URL = f"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={CITY}&appid={api_id}"
```

---

Also the following lines are incorrect:

```py
Labelc=Label(temp_celsius)
Labelf=Label(temp_farhenheit)
```

It should be:

```py
Labelc = Label(root, text=temp_celsius)
Labelf = Label(root, text=temp_farhenheit)
```

---

And I would suggest to change this line:

```py
if weatherinfo['cod'] != '404':
```

to:

```py
if weatherinfo['cod'] == 200:
```

Comment: Would it be better to put all widgets outside function and use Labelf.configure  inside function and so on?

Comment: @toyotaSupra Yes it would be, but it is not a bug and so let OP to decide what to do.

Comment: @toyotaSupra If you have better solution, write it as an answer.  Don't write useless comment like *'Try this api_id=f"abb8cea2239face8fbb7401add34d73e"'*, what the point of using *f-string* on pure string?